# sql with two table and group and result from that table?

Tags: sql

I have two tables. I need to take away from the first table second table. Stim to another table without all the rows of the first table.

**Table1**

[image]

**Table2**

[image]

```
Result  = Table1(value1) – Table2(value1) -----groupe no. 2 or no.1
```

Result  (groupe no. 2)

**Result**

```
id  value1  groupe
_______________________
1     10        2
2     9         2
3     10        2
5     5         2
6     11        2
7     12        2
```

I need the result of which I can write the group number and get result for that group.

Comment: 1     10        2 ? is it right? it should be 10-3=7?

Comment: it is working so good

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
Select 
     t1.id,
     t1.value1-t2.value1 as value,
     t1.groupe from 
     table1 t1,table2 t2 
where t1.id=t2.id and t1.groupe=2;
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I was so stupid, and I did not see that the solution is so simple

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT 
  T1.id, T2.group, T1.valor - T2.valor AS value
FROM 
   Table1 T1 INNER JOIN
   Table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.id AND T1.group = T2.group
WHERE (T1.group = 2)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I was so stupid, and I did not see that the solution is so simple.